# Adding Properties in GeoDjango

Tags: python, json, serialization, geojson, geodjango

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError at /
<Section: BILAY - 001> is not JSON serializable
```

In my views.py:

```
def display_maps(request):
    pnt = ButuanMaps.objects.get(clandpin='162-03-0001-017-33').geom
    query_section = Section.objects.all().order_by('sbrgyid__cbrgyname')
    query_soiltype = SoilType.objects.all()
    query_maps =  ButuanMaps.objects.filter(landproperty__sownerid__id=5, geom__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=100)),narea__lte =5500000)
    djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties= ['id','clandpin','ssectionid','narea'])
    geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
    butuan_agao = geoj.encode(djf.decode(query_maps.transform(3857)))
    ...
    return render(request, "index.html", {
        'butuan_agao': butuan_agao,
        'query_agao': query_maps,
        'query_section': query_section,
        'butuan_soil': butuan_soil,
        'query_soiltype': query_soiltype
    })
```

While in my models.py:

```
class ButuanMaps(gismodel.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Butuan Map'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Butuan Maps'

    clandpin = gismodel.CharField("Land PIN", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ssectionid = gismodel.ForeignKey(Section)
    narea = gismodel.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    #ssectionid_id = gismodel.IntegerField()
    geom = gismodel.MultiPolygonField("Geom ID", srid=32651, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = gismodel.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.clandpin
```

When I add `narea` and `ssectionid` on the properties it returns an error. Why? In this line:

```
djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties= ['id','clandpin','ssectionid','narea'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with the *Django.Django - GeoJSON.GeoJSON()* method.

The error is clear and tells you that your fields are "not JSON serializable".

- The first one because it is a decimal, so I guess it doesn't understand your decimal sign, weither it should a coma or point...
- The second one because it is a ForeignKey and it doesn't handle it well.

For this last issue, my advice is to remove the property from the *djf* part, decode it, put the property back into the *json-like dictionnary* and finally encode it all.

1-Get properties

```
prop = MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

2-Remove 'ssectionid'property

```
prop.remove("ssectionid")
```

3-Decode

```
djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties = prop)
decod = djf.decode(obj)
```

4-Get foreignkey values

```
 sectionlist = MyModel.objects.filter().values('ssectionid__id')
```

5-For each element of 'decod' add the property 'ssectionid'

```
for el in decod:
    el.to_dict()["properties"].update({"ssectionid": sectionlist.get(id=el.properties['id'])["ssectionid__id"]})
```

6- Encode

```
geojson = geoj.encode(decod)
```

I DO NOT say it is a GOOD answer, I say it works.

**EDIT**

The package [django-geojson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-geojson) is what you are looking for!